# save dataframe to an existing excel sheet without overwriting other information on that sheet

Tags: openpyxl, export-to-excel, pandas.excelwriter

How can I save many dataframes to different existing excel sheets without overwriting other information on those sheets and also change the date format

I tried to save first dataframe

```
       with pd.ExcelWriter('nameofmyexistingexcel.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
       mydataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="nameofexistingsheet")
```

(I tried other various options too from pandas doc and from this forum)

It does some interaction with excel, but just breaks excel file , so it can't be open anymore.

When I choose simple option of saving to a new excel, it works fine.

Comment: The Pandas method is **to_excel** . Try changing `mydataframe.to.excel` to `mydataframe.to_excel` though your code should have raised an error that mydataframe has no attribute 'to' rather than corrupting the Excel file. Other than that the code segment would write the dataframe on sheet "nameofexistingsheet" starting at cell A1 without impacting the rest of the workbook.

Comment: @moken thank you ! But actually there was no mistake in my  python code - there was  new.to_excel. I made typing mistake only on this website. My colleague have helped me to solve my case. Problem was in the existing excel - it contained merged cell in the area where dataframe had to be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sheet["A1"]` would define a cell object for cell 'A1' (first cell in excel).
To use it you need to define 'sheet' first as a Openpyxl worksheet object like below. Then you can set its attributes like 'number_format'.

```
import pandas as pd


mydataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Headers': ['Date1', 'Date2'],
                            'DatesA': ['20.10.2023', '21/10/2023'],
                            'DatesB': ['20.10.2023', '21/10/2023']
                            })

mydataframe["DatesA"] = mydataframe["DatesA"].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)
print(mydataframe.dtypes)

with pd.ExcelWriter('nameofmyexistingexcel.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    mydataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="nameofexistingsheet")

    sheet = writer.sheets['nameofexistingsheet'] # Openpyxl worksheet
    # sheet["A1"].number_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy'
    for cell in sheet['B']: # Loop column B 
        if cell.row == 1:  # Skip row 1 
            continue
        ### Apply number format to all cells in Column B to max used row
        cell.number_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy'
```

**UPDATE**
I've added the 'mydataframe' dataframe creation to my code example and updated to include two date columns.
Column 'DatesA' is datetime whereas the same dates in Column "DatesB' are default (strings)

```
       DatesA      DatesB
0  20.10.2023  20.10.2023
1  21/10/2023  21/10/2023
```

The data type for the columns is a follows

```
DatesA    datetime64[ns]
DatesB            object
```

Although I didn't include it in the example code all the Dates in columns B and C are formatted as `cell.number_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy'` using the column loop.

When the dataframe is written to Excel, the 'DatesA' Column is interpreted as dates by Excel so they take on the format of the date 'dd.mm.yyyy' whether they were that originally or using forward slash as the separator.
The 'DatesB' column is string so its recognised by Excel as a string (you can see the orientation is to the left of the cell) and the number formatting does not change the date '21/10/2023' even though its applied.

[image]

Comment: thank you! I did it, but it worked only for a certain cell - B2. could you please tell how to do it for the whole column B

Comment: I've updated the code sample to loop through Column B from row 1 to 'max row'. Assuming Row 1 is the header row, the application of number format is skipped on that row, then the number format is applied to the rest of the used cells in the column.

Comment: thank you! I have tried updated code, it does export without an error but does not change format in excel. Could you please suggest why it might be.

Comment: So if you check the number format in Excel it is not the format you are setting with number_format? Or the format is changed but Excel is not showing the date how you are setting it? If so are you using the previously mentioned format 'dd.mm.yyyy' and what does the original date look like in the dataframe, i.e. is it 'datetime64' or a string. If its a string then Excel wont recognise as a date, make sure its a date in the dataframe

Comment: thank you. Original date in dataframe had format datetime but was without hh:mm:ss, only yyyy-mm-dd. Coulmn B in resulted excel has format "all formats, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" , I created dates myself by summing day, month, year columns, then I changed their format to datetime to sort. Of course I can change format manually in excel but since there are many sheets, would be much more convienient to do it in python.

Comment: I'm not fully following where you're at, I've updated the answer to show the 'mydataframe' I used and added a duplication of the dates in a second column but did not convert them to datetime. So both columns are written to the Excel sheet you can see the datetime dates are recognised as dates by Excel and the formatting is applied. The dates that were not converted are strings and the number formatting is not applied. Hopefully this helps if that's what you are seeing.

Comment: Ultimately if there is a need to change formatting of cells you should be able to do that with Python but like I said I'm not following where the issue is now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in existing excel file - it contained merged cells in the area where dataframe had to be saved.

Currently trying to make it save dates to excel in that format: dd.mm.yyyy  without seconds.

Comment: If it's a Date Excel always saves as a serial number with h m s after decimal point if included. Its how Excel displays the data is what you are trying to change. That is the number format which you can apply after 'to_excel' writes the data using Openpyxl number_format like `sheet["A1"].number_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy'`

Comment: @moken thank you! Could you please explain sheet["A1"] - is it name of the first cell in excel where column with date is expeced to be saved or sheet name   . I tried both  variants by adding this experession after ...if_sheet_exists="overlay" , but code stopped working.